# I'm trying to send the program on launchpad and get an error

Tags: c++, c, launchpad

On my computer package is working OK.

I'm trying to send the program to launchpad
It posted normally, but does not compile, I get an error on mail:

```
* Source: not available
```

In the Build Log which shows there is an error:

```
...
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for qwe_indicator... no
configure: error: Package requirements (gtk+-3.0 glib-2.0 libcurl appindicator3-0.1) were not met:

No package 'gtk+-3.0' found
No package 'libcurl' found
No package 'appindicator3-0.1' found
...
```

I understand that there are missing packages. How can I fix it?

Comment: Install them with `apt-get`?

Comment: @molbdnilo how  did you know it wouldn't be `yum`?

Comment: @iharob A guess based on launchpad's use of Ubuntu.